# ASP.NET Webforms : async PostBack inside UpdatePanel restores the page state to when the PostBack was initiated

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `UpdatePanel` with a button that I'm using to call a postback via javascript. This will trigger a function in the code behind that will make several API calls. I'd like to make these calls asynchronous to improve performance. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```html
<%@ Page Languge="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Test" Async="true" %>

<%-- Other UI, such as inputs and tabs --%>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server"/>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest"/>
    </Triggers>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" Text="Test" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnTest" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnTest_Click" style="display:none;" runat="server"/>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= btnTest.ClientID %>").click();
    })
</script>
```

```cs
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(async () =>
                                             {
                                                 await TestAsync();
                                             }));
}

private async Task TestAsync() 
{
    var apiCall1 = FakeApiCall();
    var apiCall2 = FakeApiCall();
    var apiCall3 = FakeApiCall();

    // Runs in parallel to improve performance. Should take ~5 seconds to complete instead of ~15 seconds
    await Task.WhenAll(apiCall1, apiCall2, apiCall3);

    var result1 = await apiCall1;
    var result2 = await apiCall2;
    var result3 = await apiCall3;

    lblTest.Text = "Async Postback Finished!";
    upUpdatePanel.Update();
}

private async Task<bool> FakeApiCall() {
    Task.Delay(5000);
    return true;
}
```

However, after this partial postback finishes, it restores the page state to when the partial postback was initialized. So if I scrolled to the bottom of the page, focused a textbox, or changed tab views, etc, then all of this will be reset to when the postback was initiated.

What I expected was the page state to remain unchanged, and only the content inside the `UpdatePanel` would change.

How can I resolve this? Is this even possible, or should I use a different method like calling a WebService using AJAX and populate the UI in Javascript? But this has the downside of exposing the code and a WebMethod to the Client, and increasing the size of the js file that the Client has to download. Are there any cons for trying to do this in the code behind via an async PostBack?

Answer (score 1):

We have few things here, and we are "adding up" errors to this approach.

So, let's try and clean this up:

First up, this:

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest"/>
</Triggers>
```

Why do you have the above? You don't need nor want the above.

Remember, a update panel behaves like any plain markup. You place a standard button in the update panel, and click on that button, then to run code behind, you want to let the button cause a post-back. However, since the button (or control) event is inside of the update panel, then that is all you need here. That will thus trigger and post-back the content in the panel.

How this works is like a whole page post-back, but only the parts in the update panel are sent up to the server. This is still a classic round trip, but only for the update panel content. In fact, even the page load event in code behind will trigger/run again before your button code runs (like a regular page without a update panel).
So, remove that code.

Next up, this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" 
   UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
   OnClick="btnTest_Click" style="display:none;" 
   runat="server"/>
```

Now, I have to assume your goal to hide the button is due to you wanting to use some button click OUTSIDE of the panel to run that update panel, and cause the panel code to run, and the panel to update. That is fine (and great setup and idea on your part).
However, we don't want the addition of the use submit behaviour = false?

Simple again, remove it.

So, that button should be this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" 
   OnClick="btnTest_Click" style="display:none;" 
   runat="server"/>
```

Next up:

```
Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(async () =>
                                         {
                                             await TestAsync();
                                         }));
```

Why do you attempt to call some code asynchronously but then throw in a big can of gasoline on that that code and use an await?

Since you NOW telling the code to wait, the what good was calling an async code and then waiting for it since then you did not need to call and setup that code as asynchronous anyway!

By using await, then your code not really async any more.

So, dump that code and approach. It's not going to work here.

Next up:

```
upUpdatePanel.Update()
```

No, remove that code. You can't really use the .Update method of the update panel (it actually has near zero use). Either I spend a long explain here, but let's just zap that code, and NEVER use the .update method of a update panel - you don't need this and worse you don't want to bother.

In fact, it is extremely difficult to write code that runs behind a update panel, but then we don't see or get the update! VERY difficult to do this. In fact the sample code on MSDN attempting to do this? (it does not even work).

So, to save me writing a book here? Dump any and all use of at UP .update method in code behind. You don't need it and in fact I willing to state you will NEVER need to use that method!

Now, let's start clean here. Let's setup a working example based on all of the above.

So, our goal, or "software specification" is this:

We will have a button outside of the update panel - when clicked on it will post the update panel, and run code behind for the update panel.

When the update panel is done, we will see a label in the UP changed to "done processing".

And for good fun, while we are waiting for the code to complete, we will have an animated GIF and please wait - processing message.

So, now our markup in the update panel is this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" Text="" runat="server" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnTest" 
            OnClick="btnTest_Click" 
            OnClientClick="showwait()"
            style="display:none;" runat="server"
            ClientIDMode="Static"
            />

        <div id="myshowwait" style="display:none">
            <h3>Server Processing - please wait</h3>
            <img src="../Content/wait2.gif" style="width:32px;height:32px" />
        </div>
        <script>
            function showwait() {
                $('#myshowwait').show()
            }
        </script>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<br />
<br />
<h3>This button is outside of update panel</h3>
<h3>When clicked, it will run update panel btnTest</h3>
<br />

<asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" 
    Text="Run/Trigger update panel"
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClientClick="$(btnTest).click();return false"                
    />
```

Now, we could have used a "update progress section" for the update panel, and that will "automatic" show the content in the update progress section.

However, I went with using a simple div, a div that is "hidden" and when we click our button, we simple SHOW the div (un-hide) content. By the way, this trick works great for ANY button on a web form, and if you need a please wait message, this works great - even when not using a update panel.

So, then how and why does the div and processing gif automatic re-hide and un-show?

Well, when the update panel context is posted (due to button click), then the code behind runs, updates the content in the UP, and then that content returns back to the client side. And since the "div" has no persisted viewstate, then it returns to its normal state, and thus the div re-hides.

So now our code behind for the button:

```
Protected Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' fake a long running process

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

    lblTest.Text = "Done running server process"

End Sub
```

(It doesn't matter if this was VB or C# - the above is dead simple and will suffice for this example.

I did assume jQuery (to hide/show the div).

So, the final result looks like this:

[image]

Note how in the above screen cap animation you do NOT see a browser wait, and to the user, it looks like no post-back occurred. This also means that things like current browser scroll position etc. will be unchanged.

## Edit: Using async calls and code in the update panel

Just keep in mind, that EVERYTHING you do is STILL wrapped in a SINGLE http post and round trip. And all the async code in the world will not change this

eg:

```
 ----> http post back (full page or update panel)
       code in side here runs, can be async code, or not
       ALL code MUST finish

 <----- http post back done, 
       page markup 
       (or update panel markup returns to browser).
```

So, you can't get around the above.

OK, so to allow async methods on a page, you need to add this to your page directive async="true"

eg this:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
        CodeBehind="TestTest.aspx.cs" 
        Inherits="CSharpWebApp1.Test2.TestTest"
        Async="true"
        %>
```

OK, then for now, let's ignore the "hidden" button click issue.

We have this markup:

```
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="run code" 
                    OnClick="Button1_Click"                        
                    />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And our code behind:

```
    async Task<int> TestA()
    {
        int TestNum = 200;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        return TestNum;
    }
    async Task<int> TestB()
    {
        int TestNum = 400;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return TestNum;
    }

    async protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> MyValue = TestA();
        Task<int> MyValue2 = TestB();

        
        await Task.WhenAll(MyValue, MyValue2);    


        Label1.Text = MyValue.Result.ToString();
        Label2.Text = MyValue2.Result.ToString();

    }
```

Now, in above, since I using a "fake" set of async routines, then they are not actually async.

However, we have this:

```
 await Task.WhenAll(MyValue, MyValue2);
```

We have to "gather up" and 100% finish ALL of the async routines before we continue.

We can not (never) let the routine exit and finish, since if we do then all running code is terminated, bombed out of existence, and disposed, AND THEN the page content completes it life cycle, and is sent back to the browser.  (this is also why code that follows a Response.Redirect() never runs - the process is TERMINATED! - since you now telling asp.net to SEND the markup and "DOM" you have up on the server to the client side, and the INSTANT you do that, no further code can run server side! - nor can code continue to try and update the browser DOM after this fact!).

So, note how we are STILL having to accept the fact that we are using a http post to server, and then letting the http post complete. We are "stuck" in that http post-back model, and all the async code in the world can't change this simple fact. The Http "post" and receive is NOT a asynchronous model or setup! (so, your code inside of that round trip can be asynchronous, but you still using a single transaction at the end of the day).

What this means is that as each server side async call completes, it could in theory update the "DOM" that is also up on the server. However, any changes will not be seen by the client side until such time the post-back and return transaction is 100% complete. So, in effect changes to the browser DOM (which is currently up on the server) are in fact a type of discrete transaction. This is a limitation of the http protocol and you can't change how this works.

If you wanted to see each label or the results of each async call (the server async call) update as they complete, then you would dump the use of the update panel, and NOT use a http post-back, but make separate ajax calls from the client side to a set of routines and web methods you place on that web page.

And I suppose you could even consider moving the API calls you have server side, and move such calls to the client side JavaScript code. However, often for security reasons, you may well not want to do that.

At the end of the day, just keep in mind you are beholden to a single http "round trip", and you have to have all your results gathered up, update the controls on that page, and THEN let the cycle compete and the updated "DOM"/browser content return to the client side.

Comment: Sorry, I modified my question for clarity. I had the async logic because I'm going to make several API calls in the code behind and want to make it async to hopefully improve performance. Can you modify your answer to include async logic?

Comment: Ok, so we have a post of the UP to the server. The server code now starts calling some api's. That code behind STILL has to await, and still has to wait until such time thsoe calles are completed, and THEN and ONLY then can you allow the update panel to complete, and then return to the client side. In other words, it actually does not matter ONE tiny bit you going to make api calls sever side, you can NOT display any updates to the panel until such time the code completes and the WHOLE panel makes the trip back to the client side. So, your updated code changes nothing.

Comment: So, SURE your api calls can be async with awaits, but they still have to wait, and you can't show updates in the panel until all those api's are 100% complete. So, while your api's might be async calls, they still have to wait, and you code has to wait until those calls are 100% complete before you allow the UP panel to travel back to the client side. You can't get around this issue, and thus some api call with a await? the UP don't care, since your still waitng untill the code 100% complates and THEN you allow the panel to travel back to the client side.

Comment: If you looking to have the UP update or show things for EACH api call? then you actually don't need that up panel, and you going to make ajax calls from the client side code (JavaScript), and those calls will then be able to update the web page after each call returns its values. So, any web page, (or update panel) that travels to the server and is change by code behind? The end user does NOT see any changes untill the web page (or the UP panel) makes the trip back to the client side. So, if your code calls api's server side, you still have to wait before the UP returns to the client side.

Comment: If you need updates to show after EACH api call? Then you have to make those calls from the client side, one at a time. The client side api call could be a api call to code on the current page, which then in tern with server side code makes the api calls you doing with server side code. that code behind can then wait for the return, and when done, then you can return back to the client side js code that made that ONE call. So, no matter HOW you slice this? You can not show or display updates to the web page with code behind UNTILL you let the page (or UP) travel back to the client side.

Comment: If you want updates to show to the web page after each api call, then you have to make the ONE call from the web page (ajax api call to current page). Then code behind makes api call - you wait, and then when done, you return back to the js code that made the api call, and then that js code can update the page. So, either you keep what you have now, make all the api calls, but during those calls, you wind up with a await, and the UP panel can not (and will not) return back to client side until such time all calls are 100% complete.

Comment: so, your server side awaits are 100% fine, but they are for the api calls your code is making, and have next to nothing to do with the UP panel. So, sure, use your awaits in code behind, but you still in a use case in which you waiting for EVERYTHING to be done and all server side code has and MUST be completed before the UP travels back to the client side and shows any and all changes your code behind made to that UP.

Comment: and last but not least? If you make the api calls from the client side? You don't need nor want a UP panel anymore, since it will be of no use to allow and show  updates into the client side page  after each api call you make. Now, can you wire this up to have updates show with code behind as each api call is done? yes, but you have to adopt and introduce SignalR into this system. That library in effect sets up a websocket that allows direct communication between server code behind and the client side.

Comment: See my new edit - I show how your can use async calls in the update panel, (or even code behind for a given page).